# TikZ: Bug (?) with `.pic`: misalignement of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am using `.pic` to use a same picture several times. I noticed a difference of behavior between the same code inside a `.pic` or outside. In the example below, one can notice that within a `.pic`, the node on the edge is not at the place it should be.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{thepic/.pic = {\draw (0, 0) edge node {0} (1, 0);}}
\begin{document}
Without \texttt{.pic}: \tikz{\draw (0, 0) edge node {0} (1, 0);}
With \texttt{.pic}: \tikz{\pic{thepic};} 
\end{document}
```

The result

[image]

Is this a (known) bug?

Comment: Better picture provided. I also checked with the `article` class also defining the pic after `\begin{document}`, just to be sure: the result is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the cause for this problem, it's probably related to the path construction with `.pic`. But if you explicitly say that the node should be in the path `midway` it works normally:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{thepic/.pic = {\draw (0, 0) edge node[midway]{0} (1, 0);}}
\begin{document}
Without \texttt{.pic}: \tikz{\draw (0, 0) edge node {0} (1, 0);}
With \texttt{.pic}: \tikz{\pic{thepic};} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. The path construction with pics is not very clear to me either. But it does respect the explicit instructions given. =D